# how Send information to server with volley?

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I want to send the information to the server using the volley library and save it to the table. But after running the app no ​​data is stored in the table.

Can you tell which part is wrong?
(I did most of the things that were said on the site but my problem was not resolved)

cart.java

```
  public class cart extends AppCompatActivity {
Button Add;   
private static final String url="http://localhost/test/addpost.php";
Faculty items;
JSONArray myarray;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);
    Add=findViewById(R.id.btn_basket_pay);
    dbHandler dbh = new dbHandler(this);
    dbh.open();
    items=new Faculty();
    JSONObject JSONestimate = new JSONObject();
    myarray = new JSONArray();
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rec);
    final FacultyAdapter facultyAdapter = new FacultyAdapter(this,dbh.display());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(facultyAdapter);
    dbh.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < facultyAdapter.getItemCount(); i++) {

        try {
            JSONestimate.put("name:" + String.valueOf(i + 1), facultyAdapter.getJSONObject());
            myarray.put(facultyAdapter.getJSONObject());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Log.d("JSONobject: ", JSONestimate.toString());
    Log.d("JSONArray : ", myarray.toString());


    Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new 
            Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("onResponse", "o");
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("onErrorResponse", "o");
                }
            }){
                @Override
                public Map<String,String> getParams(){
                    Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<>();
                  params.put("jsonarray",myarray.toString());
                    return  params;

                }
            };
            queue.add(stringRequest);
            Toast.makeText(cart.this,"success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
   }}
```

I checked the php code with the postman program it worked correctly.

addpost.php

```
         <?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

require_once('dbConnect.php');

$name = $_GET['name'];
$price= $_GET['price'];
$id = $_GET['id'];

$response = array();
$server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());
$sql = "INSERT INTO tblcart (id,name,price) VALUES ('$id','$name','$price')";   
try {
    if (mysqli_query($cnn,$sql)) {
        $response = "done";
    }else{
    $response = "error";
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
        $response = "error";
} 
echo $response;
  }
   ?>
```

Comment: Put `var_dump($_GET);` at the top of the PHP code to see what you are getting.

Comment: @JayBlanchard    But it didn't solve the problem

Comment: It wasn't supposed to solve the problem, it was supposed to let us see what you were getting in the PHP code. What did it return?

Comment: @JayBlanchard  There is no value in the table to return but when I add value manually it displays the existing value.

Answer (score 1):

The url should be changed to ""http://10.0.2.2/test/addpost.php" if you want to run android virtual decive on your computer.If you use "localhost",the android virtual device will access itself.I haved this situation yesterday too.
Hope useful!

Comment: Did you add port number? try ""http://10.0.2.2:8080/test/addpost.php" or http://10.0.0.2:80/test/addpost.php"

Comment: I imported the Ip system،Other parts of the application receive information from the server and display it in the application. But in this section it does not send information to the server.